# Значение слова "слава"

Tags: этимология, семантика, синонимы

"Слава" считается родственником лексеме "слово". Так ли это? Каково значение слова  "слава"? Можно ли заменить его словом "проявление"?  Какие синонимы есть у "слова"?

Answer (score 3):

Родство **слово-слава** подчёркивается во всех словарях, в том числе и в словаре Ожегова:

Слава - 1. Почётная известность как свидетельство всеобщего уважения, признания заслуг, таланта. Неувядаемая с. С. героям! Литературная с. Орден Славы. 2. Слухи, молва (разг.). Идёт с. о ком-чём-н. Добрая с. лежит, а худая по дорожке бежит (поел.). 3. Общепринятое мнение, репутация. Хорошая, дурная с. Он пользуется славой выдающегося оратора. * Во славу кого-чего, в знай. предлога с род. п. (высок.) — ради прославления кого-чего-н. Подвиг во славу Родины. На славу (разг.) — очень хорошо. Удалось на славу. Только слава, что... (одна слава, что...) (разг. неодобр.) — только считается, говорят так, а на деле совсем иначе. Слава Богу (разг.) — 1) благополучно, хорошо. Как поживаете?— Да всё слава Богу. Опять у него дома что-то не слава Богу (неблагополучно); 2) вводн, сл, выражает удовлетворение. Дети, слава Богу, здоровы.

Синонимы: репутация, популярность, имя, реноме, бессмертие, молва, хвала; известность, знаменитость, признание, лавры; стоустая молва, слухи, станислав, мнение, исполать, краса, осанна, медные трубы, сияние, слух, ореол, ярослав, глория, слушок, толки, говор, разговоры.

Ant. неизвестность, непопулярность; репутация, реноме.

https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-79623.htm

Этимологический словарь Фасмера:

Сла́ва - "честь, похвала; слух, молва", укр. сла́ва, блр. сла́ва, др.-русск., ст.-слав. слава.  Связано чередованием гласных со сло́во, слыть.

Так что сомнений нет, долгое О читалось как А.

СЛАВА – происходит от древнего корня k'lu/k'leo-, связанного с образом увлажнения, омовения и насыщения льющейся влагой. К этому корню ученые с уверенностью возводят славянорусские слыть, слово, слышать, слух, слеза; древнегреческие κλέω «прославляю», κλύω «слышать, внимать, усваивать», имя музы Истории Клио; санскритские श्रुति (śruti «шрути») «услышанное» - название свода священных текстов древних Вед; श्रवस्  («шравас»), «слава, звук».

**Исторический словарь**  даёт **церковное значение слова - присутствие Бога или проявление Его силы** (Исх 14.17; 24.16-17; 33.18-19; Чис 14.21-22; 3Ц 8.11; Рим 6.4; От 15.8); хвала (2Пар 30.22; Лк 17.15); честь (Нав 7.19; Неем 5.13; Иер 13.16; Ин 9.24); сила и духовное влияние человека (Чис 27.20); видимое отличие (Исх 28.2,40); душа человека (Пс 56.9; 107.2).

В Священном Писании Ветхого завета Слава Божия представляет собой неслитное слитие божественных энергий сотворения и преображения мира - Сил Божиих.  **Слава является перед людьми в облаке и действует лично, представляя собой единый и нераздельный Лик, излучающий мощнейшие потоки света**: «И взы́де Моисéй на гóру, и покры́ о́блакъ гóру, и сни́де слáва Бóжiя на гóру Синáйскую, и покры́ ю́ о́блакъ шéсть днíй. И воззвá Госпóдь Моисéа в дéнь седмы́й из среды́ о́блака: обли́чiе же слáвы Госпóдни, я́ко óгнь пламенýя на версѣ́ горы́, пред сы́ны Изрáилевы. И вни́де Моисéй в средý о́блака и взы́де на гóру, и бѣ́ тáмо на горѣ́ четы́редесять днíй и четы́редесять нощéй» (Исход, 24:16-18).

Возможно, искомое значение как раз библейское - **проявление Бога**?

Не совсем поняла, с какой целью вы спрашиваете о синонимах к "слову", всё-таки у этой единицы 9 значений и к ним 89 синонимов. Самые популярные - речь, обещание, глагол, говор,  выступление, сказание,слух (о чём-то), молва, слава (дурная или хорошая), пересказ, разговор, беседа, право говорить(прошу слова), мнение, вывод, достижение (новое слово в технике), обет, текст (песня на слова...) и т.д.

Может, что есть совпадения с синонимами к слову "слава"? (слух, молва, слава)? Да, это тоже говорит об их родстве.

Comment: Мне понравилась аналогия с санскритским "шравас", а так же проведённая вами параллель, с библейским проявлением Бога. Там есть такое выражение:"И явится Бог во славе своей..." Людмила,  а вы не могли бы дополнить свой ответ синонимами языковой единице "слово"?